# Cull Particle Simulation when not visible to the camera

Tags: animation, particles, smoke-simulation

Since effects like particle Systems take a lot of memory, particularly in a big scene, can the memory use be conserved by deactivating simulations and particle systems when not within visible range of the Camera?

Not very different from viewport culling where cameras ignores drawing polygons that are behind or occluded by other objects.

The Camera would be moving, so this process have to be automated.

Answer (score 2):

I think this video is the best answer to your question [Vertex Weight Proximity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3ULsfIe1_4)

By adding arrayed plane to your camera as a child you can point which part of particles (or anything that is using vertex groups) are to show up.

[image: Example picture]
[image]
[image]